# How do I serialize a DOM to XML text, using JavaScript, in a cross browser way?

Tags: javascript, xml, dom, serialization

I have an XML object (loaded using `XMLHTTPRequest`'s `responseXML`).  I have modified the object (using jQuery) and would like to store it as text in a string.

There is apparently a simple way to do it in Firefox et al:

```
var xmlString = new XMLSerializer().serializeToString( doc );
```

(from [rosettacode](http://www.rosettacode.org/w/index.php?title=DOM_XML_Serialization#JavaScript) )

But how does one do it in **IE6 and other browsers** (without, of course, breaking Firefox)?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You can use doc.xml in internet exlporer.

You'll get something like this:

```
function xml2Str(xmlNode) {
   try {
      // Gecko- and Webkit-based browsers (Firefox, Chrome), Opera.
      return (new XMLSerializer()).serializeToString(xmlNode);
  }
  catch (e) {
     try {
        // Internet Explorer.
        return xmlNode.xml;
     }
     catch (e) {  
        //Other browsers without XML Serializer
        alert('Xmlserializer not supported');
     }
   }
   return false;
}
```

Found it [here](http://www.webdeveloper.com/forum/showthread.php?t=187378).

Comment: Thanks... I finally found this after two days of searching. (It took me a while to realize that .xml was simply not there for FF/Chrome, I had assumed I was doing something wrong.)

Comment: Webkit currently has a bug (e.g. in Chrome 19) and will not return correct XML:

xmlNode = document.createElement('img');
xmlNode.src = "test.png"
xmlNode.alt = "test"
(new XMLSerializer()).serializeToString(xmlNode);

Returns:
"<img src="test.png" alt="test">"

Comment: @cburgmer that's not an xml node

Comment: @Esailija I don't understand, what is it then? I expect XMLSerializer to serialize xmlNode into <img src… /> (note the trailing slash)

Comment: @cburgmer it's a html node, you created it using a html document. XML nodes don't have properties like `.src`. See what an actual xml element has with: `console.dir( document.implementation.createDocument( null, "xml", null ).createElement("img") )`