# jQuery: how to get xml system independently?

Tags: jquery, xml

Suppose `xmlNode` is a XML DOM node, how do you get its XML system independently?

For IE, it is `xmlNode.xml;`

For Netscape, it is `new XMLSerializer().serializeToString(xmlNode)`.

In jQuery, is there any built-in method I can leverage?

Comment: Are you stuck using XML? JSON is waaaaay easier to deal with.

Comment: No choice, our data file are all XML based, there is no way to use JSON to pass around data, which will require heavy conversion.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know of a native JQuery function to do it, but there's a cross-browser JavaScript way to get XML from an XML DOM node. Look at the xml2Str function in the answer to this Stack Overflow question:
[Serialize a DOM node to XML text using JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43455/how-do-i-serialize-a-dom-to-xml-text-using-javascript-in-a-cross-browser-way).

Answer (score 0):

```
$(xmlNode).html();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var xmlContent = $(xmlNode)
```

For a longer explination checkout the IBM developer works article on [AJAX with jQuery](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/x-ajaxjquery.html)

Comment: I don't think that works: the jQuery/$ converts the serialized form into a DOM, but not the other way around. At least I can't get it do to that.

Comment: adding .html() to the end will give you the XML as a string.

Comment: not necessarily. With DOM returned from server, I get this error: TypeError: Cannot call method 'replace' of undefined.