# How do I create and read an xml file with jquery

Tags: jquery, xml, ajax

I know there is alot of information to do this in the internet, but I got very confused.

I want to create an xml file and send it with Ajax to the server.
I will need to reseve and xml file back.

This is an example of the XML file I will need to create.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<data>
    <item>dkfjgn</item>
    <item>sdfxvv</item>
    <item>htyjhj</item>
    <item>vnmvbn</item>
    <item>qqqgdb</item>
<data>
```

As you see it is a very basic xml file. the values of the items will be contained in an array.

This is the xml file it will be send back.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<data>
    <dkfjgn>
        <title>A title</title>
        <discription>A discription</discription>       
    </dkfjgn>

    <sdfxvv>
        <title>A title</title>
        <discription>A discription</discription>
    </sdfxvv>

    <htyjhj>
        <title>A title</title>
        <discription>A discription</discription>       
    </htyjhj>

    <vnmvbn>
        <title>A title</title>
        <discription>A discription</discription>       
    </vnmvbn>

    <qqqgdb>
        <title>A title</title>
        <discription>A discription</discription>       
    </qqqgdb>
<data>
```

After reseving the xml file I want to use an "for each" on the array containing the values and look for the values and do something.

Example

```
for ( var i in values )    
{
    var title = "";
    var discription = "";

    /*********************************************************************************\
     * Each value can be obtained here by using values[i].                           *
     * If there is an other way to do this with jquery please.                       *
     * Here I will need to parse the xml file and the values in the variables above. *
    \*********************************************************************************/  
}
```

Comment: do you really need xml? because JSON is a lot easier with jQuery

Comment: +1 for JSON ;) and not only with jQuery...

Answer (score 1):

- Reading XML

http://think2loud.com/reading-xml-with-jquery/

- Writing XML

It seems there's no direct way other than building your XML with string operations. According to an answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/248297/jquery-how-to-get-xml-system-independently) "there's a cross-browser JavaScript way to get XML from an XML DOM node". The answer refers to [this another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43455/how-do-i-serialize-a-dom-to-xml-text-using-javascript-in-a-cross-browser-way).

I hope it helps.