# Save files into selected directory (javascript)

Tags: javascript, fileapi

Hello! My question is about javascript. 
I want to 
1. ask a user to select a directory 
2. then write my bunch of files to it (probably with creating sub-directories) without interaction with user

How can I do this? And can I? 
I am new in javascript and I hope for your help.

PS. 
I've heard about ability to ask a user to select a path by *save file dialog* and then save data to selected file, but i want to ask a user **once** for selecting a **directory** and then create **a bunch** of files in it **without** bothering a user for each one.

Comment: If you do this only using javascript, note that you will be saving the files onto the user's own computer (that is, the computer on which he is then using the mouse/keyboard). Is that what you want? Or did you want to write files/subdirs onto a server computer (eg. webserver)?

Comment: @gibberish
yes, i want to save my files onto the user's own computer.

Comment: Are the files coming from a webserver, or from a different location on the user's own computer? (sorry for questions, need to be sure of what you are doing)

Comment: @gibberish
Data is also generated by javascript on the fly.

PS
don't be sorry, I really thank you for your response!

Comment: I don't know what you are going to do with this, but i personally wouldn't like it if a website forces me to download (in all of the sudden) a lot of files to my computer.

Comment: @Ivotje50 for example an online-archiver, that allows to extract an archive into selected folder

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Javascript alone doesn't have any way to access the local computer's file system for WRITE purposes. Period.

However, [Downloadify](https://github.com/dcneiner/Downloadify), by [Doug Neiner](https://stackoverflow.com/users/152083/doug-neiner), was built for this purpose and uses a combination of Javascript and the Flash library.

It needs Flash 10 to work.

Alternately, you can install apache onto the computer (or better yet, a full stack like XAMPP or WAMP/MAMP/LAMP) and use PHP (with javascript/ajax) to write files onto the local file system.  However, this means that the website must also be hosted locally. Probably your best bet is [Downloadify](https://github.com/dcneiner/Downloadify)

Resources:

https://github.com/dcneiner/Downloadify

[How to create xml file with jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7152064/how-to-create-xml-file-with-jquery)

[Save content using Jquery? Write to file](http://forums.asp.net/t/1810188.aspx)

---

[Saving to server-side file using AJAX](http://problemsolv.in/2012/09/how-to-save-input-value-to-text-file-with-jquery/)

Comment: As far as i understood, with Downloadify i have to ask user for each file i want to save. Is there any way to ask user once (to select a directory) and then save a number of files without any other save dialogs?

Comment: Not that I am aware, as local write functionality is directly contrary to the security mandates of js.

Comment: I hoped that this is maybe allowed (because I ask a user for directory). Is there any way to do this? (I know that java applets can do it, but they are not user-friendly)

Answer (score 0):

The first function saveAs() get the FileSystemDirectoryHandle, creates a new subdirectory named "NewDirectoryName" and a file in it named "NewFileName.doc", then saves the content of the div in this file.

The second function saveAs2() get all the FileSystemFileHandle and FileSystemDirectoryHandle of subdirectories and files in the choosen directory. Here, I write again on the same file named "NewFileName.doc", and log all others Handle of the directory in the console.

```
<html>
<body>
<input type="button" onmousedown="saveAs()" value="Create file in directory"/>
<input type="button" onmousedown="saveAs2()" value="Overwrite any file in directory"/>
<div contenteditable id="div001"><b>Text to save in your new file</b><div>

<script>
async function saveAs(){
div001 = document.querySelector('#div001');
const opts = {mode:'readwrite'};
directoryHandle = await window.showDirectoryPicker(opts);
const subDirectory = await directoryHandle.getDirectoryHandle('NewDirectoryName', {create:true});
const file = subDirectory.getFileHandle('NewFileName.doc', {create:true});
const writable = await file.createWritable();
await writable.write(div001.innerHTML);
await writable.close();
};

async function saveAs2(){
for await([name,handle] of directoryHandle){if(name=="NewDirectoryName"){const file = await handle.getFileHandle("NewFileName.doc", {create:true});
const writable = await handle.createWritable();    
await writable.write(dv001.innerHTML);
await writable.close();
console.log(handle);
}else{console.log(handle);}}
};
</script>
</body>
</html>
```