# Download file direct to specific location using javascript

Tags: javascript

I am using `jsPDF` to generate PDF file. What I want to do is when I click save button to save the file to specific location, for example in Desktop.

So far my code does this:

```
var doc = new jsPDF();
doc.addImage(imgData, 'JPEG', 0, 0, 210, 40);
doc.save('test.pdf');
```

The .save function just gives us the opportunity to download the file, but what I want is to save the file to specific location, for example `C:\Users\username\Desktop`.

Thank you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Save files into selected directory (javascript)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20888867/save-files-into-selected-directory-javascript) (tl;dr: you can't.)

Comment: _" but what I want is to save the file to specific location, for example `C:\Users\username\Desktop`"_ Select `C:\Users\username\Desktop` at `Save File` dialog?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You can't** do that: JavaScript has no access to filesystem.

Comment: what about saving the file in cloud storage, for example in Azure cloud storage any possibility?

Comment: That's really another kind of thing, you would need to use the API (if there's one) to access the cloud storage of the user.