# Save canvas image at the specified location without using <a> element

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I want the canvas content to be saved as an image upon clicking a button.
The button's OnClientClick() is attached to the following method.
What it does is, it downloads the image and hence I needed an  element of which the id is "link".

Can someone help me to get it saved to a location that I want ?
I mean, I need to be able to specify the location for the file.

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
    function CanvasToImage() {
        var dataURL = can.toDataURL('image/png');
        document.location.href = dataURL.replace("image/png", "image/octet-stream");
        link.download = "test.png";
        link.href = canvas
            .toDataURL("image/png")
            .replace("image/png", "image/octet-stream");
        link.click();
    }
</script>
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10673122/how-to-save-canvas-as-an-image-with-canvas-todataurl

Comment: [Save files into selected directory (javascript)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20888867/save-files-into-selected-directory-javascript)