# Problem with GDataXMLParser for iPhone app

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xml, ipad, xml-parsing

Im receiving an xml format data from a CMS to my iPad app. The data in my CMS has paragraphs. The para break is represented in the XML data i receive as `<p>&nbsp;</p>`

Now when i try to build a GDataXMLDocument by

```
xmlDocument = [[GDataXMLDocument alloc]initWithData:webData options:0 error:&error];
```

it throws an error saying:

> Entity: line 2: parser error : Entity
>   'nbsp' not defined

I tried replacing the nbsp; with a space or \n character in the webData NSString object. But still whenever i try to build the xmlDocument using the above code it throws the same aforementioned error.

Any ideas on how to resolve this? I need to have paras in my content but the GDataXMLDocument isnt getting built if there are paras present. What do i do?

Answer (score 0):

1. Try encoding the file as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3805050/xml-parser-error-entity-not-defined)
2. There is a nice tutorial for [How To Read and Write XML Documents with GDataXML](http://www.raywenderlich.com/725/how-to-read-and-write-xml-documents-with-gdataxml)

Comment: hmmm i did go thru those links before itself but cudnt find a solution... ill check them once again...