# Robust way to turn text into valid XML when it contains both "&quot;" and "&nbsp;"

Tags: php, xml, parsing

From https://stackoverflow.com/a/3805286/72437 , I do know what XML cannot hold `&nbsp;`

So, if I have the following text.

```
$now = <<<'NOW'
<p><span data-farm="{&quot;animal&quot;:[&quot;dog&quot;]}">Hi &nbsp;</span></p>
NOW;
```

and I run the code.

### Method 1 - Original

```
$xml = new \DOMDocument();
if (!$xml->loadXML('<zoo-root>' . $now . '</zoo-root>')) {
    print "Not valid XML\n";
} else {
    print "Valid XML\n";
}
```

I will get invalid XML warning

> PHP Warning:  DOMDocument::loadXML(): Entity 'nbsp' not defined in
>   Entity, line: 1 in /home/cheok/Desktop/test.php on line 8 Not valid
>   XML

If I try https://stackoverflow.com/a/4311300/72437

### Method 2 - Use `html_entity_decode` and `utf8_encode`

```
$xml = new \DOMDocument();
if (!$xml->loadXML('<zoo-root>' . utf8_encode(html_entity_decode($now)) . '</zoo-root>')) {
    print "Not valid XML\n";
} else {
    print "Valid XML\n";
}
```

I will get

```
PHP Warning:  DOMDocument::loadXML(): attributes construct error in Entity, line: 1 in /home/cheok/Desktop/test.php on line 17
PHP Warning:  DOMDocument::loadXML(): Couldn't find end of Start Tag span line 1 in Entity, line: 1 in /home/cheok/Desktop/test.php on line 17
PHP Warning:  DOMDocument::loadXML(): Opening and ending tag mismatch: p line 1 and span in Entity, line: 1 in /home/cheok/Desktop/test.php on line 17
PHP Warning:  DOMDocument::loadXML(): Opening and ending tag mismatch: zoo-root line 1 and p in Entity, line: 1 in /home/cheok/Desktop/test.php on line 17
PHP Warning:  DOMDocument::loadXML(): Extra content at the end of the document in Entity, line: 1 in /home/cheok/Desktop/test.php on line 17
Not valid XML
```

The reason is that, after `html_entity_decode` and `utf8_encode`, we will get

```
<p><span data-farm="{"animal":["dog"]}">Hi Â </span></p>
```

I try the last method I known

### Method 3 - String replace

```
$xml = new \DOMDocument();
if (!$xml->loadXML('<zoo-root>' . str_replace('&nbsp;', '&#160;', $now) . '</zoo-root>')) {
    print "Not valid XML\n";
} else {
    print "Valid XML\n";
}
```

Seem to work. But, is the **Method 3** solution robust enough?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your text looks an awful lot like HTML, and [`loadHTML()`](http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.loadhtml.php) treats it just fine.

#### Example:

```
$now = <<<'NOW'
<p><span data-farm="{&quot;animal&quot;:[&quot;dog&quot;]}">Hi &nbsp;</span></p>
NOW;

$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($now, LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED | LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD);
echo $dom->saveHTML();
```

#### Output:

```
<p><span data-farm='{"animal":["dog"]}'>Hi &nbsp;</span></p>
```

---

If you want to use your original method to retain the `<zoo-root>` root element and load it as XML, create a doctype definition that defines the entity.

#### Example:

```
$now = <<<'NOW'
<p><span data-farm="{&quot;animal&quot;:[&quot;dog&quot;]}">Hi &nbsp;</span></p>
NOW;

$doctype = '<!DOCTYPE zoo-root [<!ENTITY nbsp "&#160;">]>';
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->substituteEntities = true; // Not required, just for demonstration.
$dom->loadXML($doctype . '<zoo-root>' . $now . '</zoo-root>');
echo $dom->saveXML($dom->documentElement);
```

#### Output:

```
<zoo-root><p><span data-farm="{&quot;animal&quot;:[&quot;dog&quot;]}">Hi  </span></p></zoo-root>
```