# How to ignore "undeclared entity" errors using xml_parse?

Tags: php, xml, xml-parsing

I'm getting errors like

> XML error: Undeclared entity error

When using [`xml_parse`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.xml-parse.php).

Is there an option to simply suppress these errors so that the XML parser can chug along?

If you need some example XML, here it is:

```
<schema id="foo">
    <var id="client_note_list">[CONCAT_OLD],&path_common_config;/pages/client_lists.xml</var>
</schema>
```

`&path_common_config;` isn't defined anywhere. I don't have an exhaustive list of entities that might exist either, so I can't prepend `<!ENTITY` either.

Comment: Not an interface I've used, but in other options (SimpleXML/DOMDocument) you can try [libxml_use_internal_errors](http://php.net/manual/en/function.libxml-use-internal-errors.php) with true.

Comment: @NigelRen I think that just suppresses the errors from being outputted, but doesn't allow the XML parser to continue.

Comment: @NigelRen Can you even do it with SimpleXML? I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3805050/65387) but they're all hacks.