# Why is the XML property missing in DOM Document object in browsers other than IE

Tags: javascript, xml, dom, cross-browser, domparser

I think this property is quite useful,

http://www.w3schools.com/Dom/prop_document_xml.asp

But as you can see, it's only available in IE.

Is there an equivalent of this property in other browsers?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: possible dupicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43455/how-do-i-serialize-a-dom-to-xml-text-using-javascript-in-a-cross-browser-way

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The xml property is non-standard. The equivalent in other browsers is XMLSerializer.

```
function serializeXmlNode(xmlNode) {
    if (typeof window.XMLSerializer != "undefined") {
        return (new window.XMLSerializer()).serializeToString(xmlNode);
    } else if (typeof xmlNode.xml != "undefined") {
        return xmlNode.xml;
    }
    return "";
}
```