# XML construction using Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml

Our app has a weird requirement which is to construct an xml using javascript and send that back to server as string.

I tried with jquery like this

```
$xmlT = $("<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?><root></root>");

            $root = $("<notebook></notebook>"); //.attr("title", roottitle).            
            $root.attr("title", title);
            $root.attr("id", id);


            $root.appendTo($xmlT);
```

but am not able to get the xml as string back from the above variable.

is there some  way or library using which i can construct xml and access that as string?

Regards,
Jeez

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found these jquery plugins [xml2json](http://www.fyneworks.com/jquery/xml-to-json/) & [json2xml](http://michalkorecki.com/content/introducing-json-xml-jquery-plugin) which is close to what I was looking for, if not the same.

For more info check stackoverflow entry[XML <-> JSON conversion in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1773550/xml-json-conversion-in-javascript)

Answer (score 1):

You can do things like createElement() etc on the XMLDoc returned from XMLHttpRequest.responseXML

http://www.w3schools.com/dom/dom_nodes_create.asp

So perhaps you can use XMLHttpRequest without actually doing a request, so you can get an object to manipulate.

You could then serialise the XML Dom using the XMLSerializer (for firefox) or xmlNode.xml for IE (metioned here [How do I serialize a DOM to XML text, using JavaScript, in a cross browser way?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43455/how-do-i-serialize-a-dom-to-xml-text-using-javascript-in-a-cross-browser-way/43468#43468))

Answer (score 0):

You could take a look at [this](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/createXMLDocument) plugin

Comment: thanks for the reference but i was looking for plugin which would work the other way