# HTML5 sessionStorage and XMLDocument

Tags: javascript, html, sessionstorage

I want to store an XML document in `sessionStorage`. When I do this it seems to save ok as an `XMLDocument`.  When I try to access it (on a page refresh) the object comes back as `[object Object]` as opposed to `[object XMLDocument]`.

How do I get the data out of `sessionStorage` as an `XMLDocument` (or convert it to one?)

Comment: Did you try new XMLDOcument(object)?

Comment: @FelixKling How do I convert from (jQuery) xml to a String and then back again?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`localStorage` and `sessionStorage` can only hold strings. Have a look at the [interface definition](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Storage#sessionStorage):

```
interface Storage {
  readonly attribute unsigned long length;
  [IndexGetter] DOMString key(in unsigned long index);
  [NameGetter] DOMString getItem(in DOMString key);
  [NameSetter] void setItem(in DOMString key, in DOMString data);
  [NameDeleter] void removeItem(in DOMString key);
  void clear();
};
```

You cannot store objects unless you serialize them. So in your case, you have to [serialize it to XML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43455/how-do-i-serialize-a-dom-to-xml-text-using-javascript-in-a-cross-browser-way).

If you received the XML document as text, just store it directly. You can use [`jQuery.parseXML()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseXML/) to parse it after retrieval.

Comment: `JSON.stringify()` is one possible method.

Comment: How can I serialize my XML (using jQuery) to a String ?

Comment: @alex: Probably does not work with XMLDocument. I assume it as circular references. But for "plain objects" you are right.

Comment: Thanks so far but how do I convert from jQuery XML document to XMLDocument?

Comment: for JSON, there is JSON.Stringify. There must be something similar for xml.

Comment: You should have a look at the documentation. There it states that `jQuery.parseXML()` returns an `XMLDocument`.

Answer (score 4):

You may want to serialize XMLDocument before saving it in storage:

```
var xml = new XMLSerializer().serializeToString(originalDom);
sessionStorage.setItem("myDocument", xml);
```

and then unserialize after loading data from storage:

```
var xml = sessionStorage.getItem("myDocument");
var restoredDom = new DOMParser().parseFromString(xml, "text/xml");
```

Comment: But new XMLSerializer().serializeToString(originalDom); not completely converting childs into proper string.