# serialize chosen decorated select box?

Tags: javascript, jquery-chosen

Is there any way to serialize html form element decorated with chosen.
Here is html fragment:

```
<select data-placeholder="Please select a community..." multiple="multiple" class="community-select chzn-done" id="selBBJ" style="display: none;">
      <option></option>
      <option value="26">Awesome Private Community</option>
      <option value="1">Global Community</option>
      <option value="28">just another public community</option>
      <option value="25">New Awesome Public</option>
      <option value="27">Ololo community</option>
</select>
```

**$(#some-select).val()** return values
But $(#some-select).serialize() - return empty array..
Other elements without **multiple** serialized correctly..
How to do it right?

Here is code to play [code on jsbin](http://jsbin.com/ojuyub/1/edit)

Comment: if you'd like to serialize it to XML, have a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43455/how-do-i-serialize-a-dom-to-xml-text-using-javascript-in-a-cross-browser-way) SO thread

Comment: I want serialize it to query params list like param1=12&param2=45