# HTML Produces <br> Instead of XML <br /> or <br></br>

Tags: html, xml, ajax

Trying to parse some XML and then insert specific parts into various HTML elements.

I'm using the innerHTML routine and whenever I insert `<br>` tags, formatting as `<br />` or `<br></br>` in the XML document it automatically ignores the `/` and formats it to `<br>`

XML source:

```
&lt;br /&gt;
```

I have tried various things like replacing the `/` with the HTML character codes, but still it inserts `<br>`.

**I want `<br />` OR `<br></br>`
Why isn't this working?**

EDIT:

XML File:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<questionContainer>

    <title>What is this?</title>

    <body>
    &lt;br /&gt;
    This is the login form to access the KayPop beta. New beta testers are accepted weekly, find our more or... 

    &lt;br / &gt;&lt;br / &gt;
    &lt;a href="#"&gt;Sign up here!&lt;/a&gt;
    </body>


</questionContainer>
```

Javascript Routine:

```
function insertXML()
    {
        $.ajax ({
            type: "GET",
            url: 'cd_catalog.xml',
            dataType: "xml",
            success: function( xml )
            {           
                $(xml).find('questionContainer').each(function(){
                    var title = $(this).find('title').text();
                    document.getElementById('q-T').innerHTML = title;

                    var bodyText = $(this).find('body').text();
                    document.getElementById('q-B').innerHTML = bodyText;
                });
            }
        });
    }
```

Procuded HTML (viewed in Chrome -> Inspect Element):

http://i.imgur.com/0bq3q.png

Comment: What is the doctype and what are you using to parse (the innerHTML suggests JavaScript)?

Comment: regardless of anything else, an xHTML line break tag should be `<br />` -- `<br></br>` is not valid; it has to be a self-closing tag.

Comment: Not to point to the obious, but you are using `innerHTML` - so I would expect to get HTML back - not XML like you do.

Comment: If you mean that it shows up as `<br>` in the DOM tree, that's perfectly fine. Or where exactly are you seeing the `<br>`s and how do you "insert specific parts into various HTML elements"?

Comment: in what context are you working? is this a Javascript program doing this in the browser? What doctype is the HTML using?

Comment: XML: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>

Comment: `&lt;br \/&gt;` maybe? do you need to escape the / in a string?

Comment: okay, that's the XML document, but what about the doctype of the HTML document you're loading it into?

Comment: Also please show your code otherwise it's a real guessing club here.

Comment: @SDC: `<br></br>` *is* valid XHTML.

Comment: @BoltClock - it's been a long while since I used xhtml in anger, but I was always under the impression that it wasn't. Maybe they always said that just for backward compatibility's sake? I never really thought to check. In any case, I would guess the core issue here is likely because the document isn't using an xhtml doctype anyway.

Comment: Possible duplicate of: [How do I serialize a DOM to XML text, using JavaScript, in a cross browser way?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/43455/367456)

Comment: @SDC — it is valid XHTML but not HTML Compatible (as per Appendix C) XHTML.

Comment: @SDC: It's simply because it's XML-based.

Comment: Well I did learn XHTML from w3schools which I now know to be rather unreliable from w3fools, so I should probably reread how to define an XHTML document unless <!DOCTYPE html> is proper? ALso guys, really appreciate the downvoters if they tell me why they downvoted... I have also edited the post to include all relevant code.

Comment: I'd strongly recommend not using XHTML. It is almost always far more trouble then it is worth. The [XHTML syntax for HTML 5](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/the-xhtml-syntax.html#xhtml) is somewhat scary and includes this gem: * This is not strictly a violation of the XML specification, but it does contradict the spirit of the XML specification's requirements.*. For any webpage that isn't being generated by a very-very-xml backend, I'd recommend plain HTML 5 (or HTML 4 Strict).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The browser keeps a representation of the DOM in memory.

When you read `innerHTML` it will serialise the DOM to HTML.

There is no way to make a browser serialise it to XHTML, or to control which HTML syntax it will use when there are multiple ways to represent something (i.e. you cannot state a preference for `<p id=1>` over `<p id="1">` or vice versa (ditto `<br>`, `<br />`, `<br></br>`).

If you want XHTML, you will need to walk the nodes in the DOM and render them as XHTML yourself.

Comment: Suggested link: [How do I serialize a DOM to XML text, using JavaScript, in a cross browser way?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/43455/367456)