# Is it possible in JavaScript to get html page code and replace TextBoxes with it's values?

Tags: javascript, html

I kind of need to create html page copy by clicking on button in this page, but where all `<input type = 'text'...` replaced with it's values.

I think, I can handle the second part, but how first to get html code?
Are this ever possible?

I need this for generating html reports.
Page is shown in internal browser of my prog. The basic idea, the student see the page with inputs, then when he fill all, he press button inside HTML page, some JS handler work and send to my prog same page, but without inputs for later review for teacher.

Comment: you mean you need to make a new version of a page re-loading it with the input values. With input field on new page or without?

Comment: Maybe this SO question would help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/982717/how-do-i-get-the-entire-pages-html-with-jquery

Comment: yes it is could you please share your html code

Comment: Page is shown in internal browser of my prog. The basic idea, the student see the page with inputs, then when he fill all, he press button inside HTML page, some JS handler work and send to my prog same page, but without inputs. This is kind of creating report.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to get the html for the body of the document, use this:

```
document.body.innerHTML
```

You can then modify it as needed and change it:

```
document.body.innerHTML = ... modified html ...
```

There are better ways to achieve the result though, like manipulating the DOM with [jQuery](https://jquery.org/).

Comment: could I use document.innerHTML to receive whole page starting from html tag? I am kind of far from work place where I can check in steps mode

Comment: @Kosmos, `document` itself does not have `innerHTML`.  The closest thing is `document.firstChild.innerHTML` which will be everything inside `html` tags.

Comment: Thank you, this should be enough for me

Comment: @SamuelNeff, does the input values get collected by `document.body.innerHTML` before they are submitted?

Comment: I think I will do simple string replace of inputs with it's values. I have an array where all inputs is stored, so when I got html page, I will run through it's tags and replace what needed.

Answer (score 2):

You can use document DOM element and serialize it:

(new XMLSerializer()).serializeToString(document);

for cross-browser compatibility see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43455/how-do-i-serialize-a-dom-to-xml-text-using-javascript-in-a-cross-browser-way) post

Answer (score 1):

If you have a `<form>` you can post to the same page adding `?post=1` to the `action`.

Then in the php

```
if ($_GET["post"]==1) { 
//same table or div structure getting the values submitted by the form
}
```

Do you know how to do it? was this you needed?

Comment: Thank you, but this is for PHP, but in my prog there is only pure html / js is loaded, so I needed solution for this. Sorry for not full explaining this in base question