# XpathResult - Get entire xml not just content

Tags: javascript, xml, xpath

When using Xpath in JavaScript is there a way to extract the full content of a result, including tags, as a string?

For example:

```
<myitems>
    <item>item1</item>
    <item>item2</item>
</myitems>
```

Can the results of '//myitems' be used to print:

```
<item>item1</item>
<item>item2</item>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with `RegExp` like following:

```
var str = "<myitems><item>item1</item><item>item2</item></myitems>";

var reg = /<(\w+)>(.*)<\/\1>/;
var ret = reg.exec(str);

console.log(ret[2]); // returns <item>item1</item><item>item2</item>
```

<kbd>[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dqBr7/)</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

You asked this question two days ago here:

[JavaScript Xpath: return result as string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22527545/javascript-xpath-return-result-as-string/22532851#22532851)

and failed to respond to the answer. Why are you asking it again?

Comment: When I last checked there were two answers (not yours but another) that misunderstood the question so I thought I'd rephrase it in a clearer way. I should have just edited it though, something that didn't occur to me at the time.